# telegrambot python edit photo

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

делаю бота в телеграм нечего такого но мне нужно изменить предыдущее сообщение с фото на несколько фото
Bot.send_message_media_group
У меня работает но как я понимаю
Bot.edit_message_media_group Этого аргумента как я понимаю нету телеграм боте
Это можно как то заменить или что-то вроде того?